# References.bib not working

Tags: bibliographies

In the process of writing my report, I am adding the sources and articles I used.

**This what I include in thesis.tex file:**

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

{\small 

\bibliography{references}

 }
```

**and in reference.bib file, an example:**

```
 @article{    Etienne2015,

 author = "\'Etienne, Jocelyn and Fouchard, Jonathan and Mitrossilis,
      D\'emosth\`ene and Bufi, Nathalie and Durand-Smet, Pauline
      and Asnacios, Atef",

title       = "Cells as liquid motors: Mechanosensitivity emerges from
      collective dynamics of actomyosin cortex",

 journal    = "Proc Natl Acad Sci USA",

 year       = "2015",

 volume = "112",

 issue      = "9",

  pages     = "2740--2745",

  doi       = "10073/pnas.1417113112"

   }
```

But it does not work. It just put "references" in the title and nothing is added! Any help!

Comment: did you run bibtex?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If you meant \usepackage{bibtex}, yes I did, but it appears bibtex as word in the pdf

Comment: `\usepackage{bibtex}` will not work since there is no `bibtex` package. You'll want to run the prohgram BibTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Answer (score 1):

There are two, but incompatible, ways of making a bibliography in LaTeX.

- Using `\usepackage{natbib}` combined with running back-end `bibtex` on your `.tex` file.
- Using `\usepackage{biblatex}` combined with running the back-end `biber` on your `.tex` file.

---

For use of `\usepackage{natbib}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

See \cite{Etienne2015}.

\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

On most editors you need to select a special compile option to run `bibtex`. Bibtex prepares information from the `.bib` file to display in LaTeX.

If you can't run bibtex from your editor (if you don't know whether you can, ask me in the comments), you need to open a terminal (on Windows, go in explorer to the directory containing your `.tex` file and enter `cmd` in the address bar). First compile your `.tex` normally. Then execute `bibtex ...` in the terminal, where `...` is the name of your `.tex` file (without the `.tex` extension). Now compile again.

---

For use of `\usepackage{biblatex}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
See \cite{Etienne2015}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

On most editors you need to select a special compile option to run `biber`. Biber prepares information from the `.bib` file to display in LaTeX.

If you can't run biber from your editor (if you don't know whether you can, ask me in the comments), you need to open a terminal (on Windows, go in explorer to the directory containing your `.tex` file and enter `cmd` in the address bar). First compile your `.tex` normally. Then execute `biber ...` in the terminal, where `...` is the name of your `.tex` file  (without the `.tex` extension). Now compile again.

Comment: Standard reference for the very last bit of the answer (running Biber in an editor): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864